# Message: CSRF attack detected

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-ec2, cdn, kentico

I am trying to solve this issue.

I have two cdn url  abc.com pointing to elb1 and def.com pointing to elb2.

Both elb (elb1 and elb2) pointing to same ec2 instances which is load balanced(ec2-A and ec2-B)

I can login to the server which is navigated from abc.com 
but i am unable to login to the server which is navigated from def.com

def.com login gives following error.

Since both dns points to same EC2. Web.config files are same.

```
Message: CSRF attack detected.

Exception type: CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfException
Stack trace: 
at CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfProtection.ThrowCsrfException(Exception innerException)
at CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfProtection.OnPostMapRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler[TArgs](EventHandler`1 h, TArgs e)
at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise[TArgs](String partName, List`1 list, TArgs e, Boolean important)
at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e)
at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e)
at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.StartEvent(TArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Message: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

Exception type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Stack trace: 
at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input)
at CMS.Protection.Web.UI.CsrfProtection.OnPostMapRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
```

Comment: It looks like you send post requests from external website

Comment: Seems like the machineKeys do not match. Have a look at this: https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/optimizing-website-performance/setting-up-web-farms/configuring-web-farm-servers#Configuringwebfarmservers-ConfiguringthemachineKeyelementinweb.config Could you please specify what HF version you are using?

Comment: its kentico 10 latest

Comment: Are you using auto-generated encryption keys (machineKey)? Can you confirm the issue still exists after following the steps described in the documentation linked in the previous comment?

Comment: yes its auto-generated, but as per the comment above i am generating again, i have see that machine key section in web.config

Comment: also i have noticed webfarm is not working

Comment: hostname does not flip in system module

Comment: its fixed, i generated machine key, and put the same machine key in both ec2 instances. hence the issues is fixed

Answer (score 2):

CSRF protection in Kentico validates the tokens using the MachineKey.Unprotect() method, therefore it is necessary that all servers use the same encryption keys.

See the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/optimizing-website-performance/setting-up-web-farms/configuring-web-farm-servers#Configuringwebfarmservers-ConfiguringthemachineKeyelementinweb.config) for more details about how to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Add the following key in the appSettings of your web.config

```
<add key="CMSEnableCsrfProtection" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

its fixed, i generated machine key, and put the same machine key in both ec2 instances. hence the issues are fixed

Answer (score -1):

Neshi is correct and you need to ensure, that the post request on the page comes from the same source otherwise you pretty much fulfill definition of cross site scripting.

Overall setup is quite complex, however you still need to ensure that security token in CSRF cookie is the same as token generated by CMSPage on load and I am not sure if these redirects and load transfers are able to do so as well as to keep session sticky enough.

General description is at: 
https://docs.kentico.com/k10/securing-websites/developing-secure-websites/cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-xsrf